# beautifulsoup selecting certain values only

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is part of the webpage source code.

```html
   <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/docdollars/doctors/pid/36602">
        <h6>Jane</h6>
      </a>
         Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians/Internal Medicine
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>NY Medical Ctr<br>New York City, 
      <a href="/docdollars/states/NY">NY</a>
      </p>
    </td>                
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/docdollars/doctors/pid/1091514">
        <h6>Greg</h6>
      </a>
         Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians/Family Medicine
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>57950 NYC<br>New York City, 
      <a href="/docdollars/states/NY">NY</a>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I expect the scraped data looking like this:

```
Jane, Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians/Internal Medicine, NY Medical Ctr, New York City, NY 
Greg, Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians/Family Medicine, 57950 NYC, New York City, NY
```

My codes (below) are working partially (see comments below).

```
for i in item.find_all('tr'):
    print i.find('a').find('h6').text  #working fine
    print i.find('td').next_sibling.next_sibling.find('p').text.strip()  # this needs revision
    print i.find('td').text.strip()  # this needs revision
```

Thanks for your suggestion in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on finding the `<h6>` elements, using a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), then find the accompanying info from there:

```
for header in soup.select('tr td a h6'):
    name = header.get_text(strip=True)
    practice = header.parent.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()
    address = header.find_parent('td').find_next_sibling('td').get_text(' ', strip=True)
    print name, practice, address
```

So this finds all `h6` elements contained in a `<tr><td><a>` wrapper. From there, we can go back up to the parent (the `<a>` link) and find the next piece of text, and also find the parent `<td>` element to find the next `<td>` containing the remaining text.

Given your sample input in a variable named `soup`, that produces:

```
>>> for header in soup.select('tr td a h6'):
...     name = header.get_text(strip=True)
...     practice = header.parent.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()
...     address = header.find_parent('td').find_next_sibling('td').get_text(' ', strip=True)
...     print name, practice, address
... 
Jane Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians/Internal Medicine NY Medical Ctr New York City, NY
Greg Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians/Family Medicine 57950 NYC New York City, NY
```